# Run .exe file from code behind asynchronously

Tags: c#, web-applications, executable, code-behind

I have a console application that writes on a txt files information retrieved from a database. Until now I manually executes the executable generated by the console application.

Now I need to automatize the invocation of the .exe from my web application, so that each time a specific condition happens in my code behind I can run the .exe with a logic "fire and forget".

My goals are:

1) Users must not be affected in any way by the console application execution (the SQL queries and txt file generation might take around 3 to 5 minutes), therefore the logic of "fire and forget" delegated to a separate process.

2) Since the executable will be still run manually in some cases, I would prefer having the all logic in one place, in order to avoid the risk of having a different behaviour.

Can I safely use **System.Diagnostics.Process** to achieve this?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process cmd = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
cmd.Start("Logger.exe");
```

Does the process automatically ends or do I have to set a timeout and explicitly close it? 
Is it "safe" in a web application environment with different users accessing the web application let them call the executable without the risk of concurring accesses?
Thanks.

EDIT:
Changed to use the built in class for more clarity, thanks for the hint.

Comment: CommandLineProcess seems to be some custom class. Consider using built in classes when asking questions or at least provide reference to documentation/source.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the mechanics, I assume CommandLineProcess wraps Process? If so, I don't see anything necessarily wrong with it, at first glance. I just have some issue with running this as an executable from a web application, as you are more likely to reduce security to get it working than rearchitect (if you follow the normal path I see in development).

If you encapsulate the actual business code in a class library, you can run the code in the web application. The main rule is the folder it saves to should be under webroot (physically or logically) so you don't have to reduce security. But, if the logic is encapsulated, you can run the "file creeator" in the web process without spinning up a Process.

Your other option is wrap the process in a service (I like a non-HTTP WCF service, but you can go windows service, if you want). I would only go this direction if it makes sense to follow a SOA path with a service endpoint. As this is likely to be isolated to a single application, in process makes more sense (unless you are saving to a directory outside of webroot).

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: (+1) The web application runs in a intranet, no external access is allowed and IPs are filtered to allow only some subnets to be able to access it.The .exe is generated by a console application previously developed by us and would be used only by my web app. I wanted to use it directly to avoid having to re-write the code, but mainly to let it invoke asynch since the generation of txt files might take up to 5 minutes (even so no issue with concurrent accesses?). Moreover in some cases the exe must be executed manually, therefore having all the code is just one place would be better.

Comment: I am still a bit leery about web applications, but the security issue might not be as paramount. What triggers the need to update? If possible, can you have the same application that makes the change (perhaps it is your web app?) do the work?

Comment: As example a new client creation within the web app is a trigger that should create the txt files. I could do this in the web application itself, but it would let the user wait up to 3-5 minutes before returning back the control. From this my idea was to detach the generation of the txt files. I was also thinking to a scheduled task that every 5 mins runs the .exe. I would modify the console app to make first a lookup on a specific table on the DB (filled by the web app when a trigger occurs) and generate the txt files only if that table has the proper flag enabled and reset it once executed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will die on it's own - provided that the .exe file will terminate on it's own. It will run with the same credentials of the web server.

Keep in mind this is considered unsafe, since you are executing code based on whatever your webapp is doing. However, the problem is with .exe files being executed this way in general and not with the actual users accessing the app.

Similar question here [How do I run a command line process from a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693829/how-do-i-run-a-command-line-process-from-a-web-application)